# How to enable --control-flow-collections

Tags: dart

Trying to use Dart 2.3's new for() syntax in Flutter and the IDE provides an error stating: "This requires the --control-flow-collections experiment to be enabled".  How do I enable this?

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks the other question did help me figure it out but can't mark my question as duplicate cause original question has not yet accepted an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458433/flutter-flow-control-collections-are-needed-but-are-they