# flutter --flow-control-collections are needed, but are they?

Tags: flutter, dart, upgrade

After upgrading flutter (both master and stable versions) and dart, I get an error about the experiment --flow-control-collections not being enabled for various for-loops that I'm using in the project. I tried to fix it using [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477046/how-can-i-enable-flutter-dart-language-experiments) but that just made things weirder.  So, now I have the below error that tells me that I need the control-flow-collections experiement to be enabled while simultaneously telling me that it's no longer required.

[image: eex]

This error comes up for every for-loop that I'm using.

Here's my flutter --version result:

```
Stable:
Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 27321ebbad (13 days ago) • 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
Engine • revision 2994f7e1e6
Tools • Dart 2.7.0

Master:
Flutter 1.13.6-pre.16 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fcaf9c4070 (2 days ago) • 2019-12-21 14:03:01 -0800
Engine • revision 33813929e3
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.0.0 886615d0f9)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

*Hey, I had the same issue this morning but found a fix.*

1) Keep the analysis_options.yaml in your root folder with this code:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - control-flow-collections
```

2) Don't use brackets {} in between your for loops
**Ex:**

```
<Widget>[
  for (final category in categories) 
    CategoryWidget(category: category)
],
```

**3) Important step which is probably why it's not working for you:**
Change your Dart version constraint in the pubspec.yml file in your root folder to 2.5.2

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.2 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Flag `control-flow-collections` is no longer required

Comment: 2.2.2 as min version, pub get, removing brackets of if() and restarting AndroidStudio was enough for me.

Answer (score 31):

Change dart version in pubspec.yml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

then

```
 flutter pub get
 flutter clean
```

**And restart Android Studio**

Answer (score 18):

Even after changing the `dart version` didn't work, then just restart your `VS Code` or whatever editor you're using. Then check if the error is there. If so, then run `flutter clean`.

Answer (score 1):

I had also this issues in my project, and I resolved my issues by following this steps:

1. SDK: ">=2.5.2 <3.0.0"
   2.Run **flutter clean**
   3.Restart **VSCode**