# How to enable control-flow-collections expriment

Tags: flutter, dart

I an trying to insert more picture from `api` to `json`

```
new Carousel(
          images:[
            for(var i=0 ;i<8;i++){
            NetworkImage("https://tdiscount.tn/modules/zeroslideshow/views/img/slideImages/"+data[i]["results"])}
          ],
          boxFit: BoxFit.fill,
          autoplay: true,
          animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          dotSize: 4.0,
          indicatorBgPadding: 4.0,
        ),
```

**Error:** `This requires the 'control-flow-collections' experiment to be enabled. (experiment_not_enabled at [flutter_app] lib\main.dart:57)`

Comment: What version of Dart are you using?  control-flow-collections should be enabled by default in Dart 2.3 or later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter --flow-control-collections are needed, but are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458433/flutter-flow-control-collections-are-needed-but-are-they)

Comment: i use version 2.8.0 of dart

Comment: i use version 2.8.0 of dart